# Construct Date String on parameter

Tags: php

currently, I have this code

```
if($format === "ymd") {
    self::$string = $year."/".$month."/".$date;
    return self::$string;       
}

if($format === "dmy") {
    self::$string = $date."/".$month."/".$year;
    return self::$string;
}
```

what i want is according to format input i.e ymd,dmy etc i want the date pattern update like to the given parameter. Is it possible at all

Comment: I agree with the answerer that DateTIme objects will be better for handling dates. But conceptually, your code should be possible, provided it is contained within a static function, and `$string` is declared as a static property in your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much easier if you are handling dates properly in PHP.

```
// create a new datetime object
$date = new \DateTime('2000-10-01');

$pattern1 = 'm/d/Y';
$pattern2 = 'd/m/Y';

// output it according to your pattern.
echo $date->format($pattern1);    // 10/01/2000
echo $date->format($pattern2);    // 01/10/2000
```

constructing your dates like you are is very limited as proper `::DateTime` objects are really powerful.  They can be converted between timezones, added to, subtracted from, compared with, modified using text strings etc.